# Deleting a linked list element causes an infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, infinite

I am writing a program that takes a list of integers in input, and based on the integer it performs the following operations:

1. remove the absolute value if the value in input is negative
2. If the number is positive and even, then add in on the top of the list
3. If the number is positive and odd, add it on the tail of the list
4. If the number is equal to zero, end the program and print the list.

My problem is with the pop_el function, which causes an infinite loop on the list, so when i print the list the program goes into an infinite loop.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ll_node_S * ll_node_ptr;
struct ll_node_S
{
    int v;
    ll_node_ptr next;
};
typedef struct ll_node_S ll_node;

ll_node_ptr push_tail(ll_node_ptr head, int v)
{
    ll_node_ptr backup = head;
    ll_node_ptr current = head;

    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = (ll_node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(ll_node));
    current->v = v;
    return backup;
}

ll_node_ptr push_head(ll_node_ptr head, int v)
{
    ll_node_ptr new_head = (ll_node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(ll_node));
    new_head->v = v;
    new_head->next = head;
    return new_head;
}

ll_node_ptr pop_el(ll_node_ptr head, int el)
{
    ll_node_ptr backup = head;
    ll_node_ptr current = head;
    ll_node_ptr previous = NULL;
    int found = 0;

    while(current != NULL && !found)
    {
        if(current->v == el)
        {
            if(previous == NULL)
            {
                backup = current->next;
                free(current);
                current = backup;
                previous = current;
            }
            else
            {
                previous->next = current ->next;
                free(current);
                current = current->next;
            }

            found = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return backup;
}

void print(ll_node_ptr head)
{
    ll_node_ptr current = head;
    printf("%d\n", head->v);
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
        printf("%d\n", current->v);
    }   
}

int isPair(int n)
{
    return ((n % 2) == 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 1;
    ll_node_ptr list = NULL;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if(n < 0)
        {
            list = pop_el(list, -n);
        }
        else
        {
            if(isPair(n))
            {
                list = push_head(list, n);
            }
            else
            {
                list = push_tail(list, n);
            }

        }


    }

    print(list);
    //should free the list
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the test case (passed in input) i am testing the code against:

```
4
5
2
-4
-5
-3
9
2
0
```

which should produce the following output:

```
2
2
9
```

any clues?

Comment: Debugger would help.

Comment: i am developing the program on the cloud9 environment using a custom script to cat the test case and pipe it into the program, therefore i can't use the debugging tools provided by c9 (which aren't working when using a c environment)

Comment: You should invest in some development environnment on your local machine if you want to work efficiently. And by "investment" I don't necessarily mean "money" but rather "time".

Comment: Then use offline tools like gcc and gdb which are free and open source. You can't just come here and ask from someone to debug it for you.

Comment: i am using a chromebook, and as far as i know, gdb isn't supported on them.
Plus, i can't use my desktop pc(normally i would just copy-paste the code on visual studio and start debugging), since i am on vacation (first semester of university just finished).
The only reason i posted the code on stackoverflow is that i don't have other ways to solve my problem

Comment: It really isn't our problem that you do not have a fully-functional development environment in which to work.  That isn't an excuse for ignoring [our community standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), which include exerting a reasonable effort to solve the problem yourself before turning to us.

Answer (score 1):

Several things,

In `pop_el`,

1.If `previous` is `NULL` then you just need to move your `head` ptr to the next node. So that it will become new `head`.

```
if(previous == NULL)
{
    backup = current->next;
    free(current);      
    //current = backup;   ---> Not needed.
    //previous = current; ---> Not needed.
    break;  //            ---> No need of setting found flag. You can remove it
}
```

2.If previous is not `NULL` then you need to just point the `previous` node next ptr to the `current` node's next node.

```
else
{
    previous->next = current ->next;
    free(current);          
    //current = current->next; ---> Not needed.
    break;  //            ---> No need of setting found flag. You can remove it
}
```

3.In `push_tail` you are allocating memory for `current->next` node and in the next line you are adding `v` to current node's `v`. That's wrong. Check following,

```
ll_node_ptr push_tail(ll_node_ptr head, int v)
{
    ll_node_ptr backup = head;
    ll_node_ptr current = head;
    ll_node_ptr new = NULL; // Created new pointer
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    //current->next = (ll_node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(ll_node));
    new = (ll_node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(ll_node));
    //current->v = v;   ----> incorrect. new Value is actually replacing the old value.
    new->v = v;       // New value is added in the newly created node.
    new->next = NULL;
    current->next = new;
    return backup;
}
```

4.You can improve your `print` logic

```
void print(ll_node_ptr head)
{
    ll_node_ptr current = head;
    //printf("%d\n", head->v);
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", current->v);
        current = current->next;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please note that both OP's original code and your code for the `push_tail()` function invoke undefined behavior when `head` is a `NULL` pointer. Exactly this happens if the first number entered by the user is odd.

Comment: Also, you have a memory leak. You DO need the `free(current)` that you commented out in `pop_el()`. It is difficult to fix-up poorly designed code like this, and better to start from scratch. That is one reason that I left `pop_el()` alone for the most part in my answer, and only suggested that it should be rewritten and simplified. The original code did work, and did not leak memory.

Comment: Yes. `free(current)` is needed. I missed this. Thanks

Comment: I agree with you. It is difficult to fix the code with this design. But we should try to provide fix to the issue/error for the existing design only and also guide user for better logic. User has written some logic by himself. If we give our logic then there is no learning here. He will do just copy paste. Learning is important here.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem can be solved by fixing the `push_tail()` function, as pointed out by @Vitek. The original code not only stored the value in the wrong node, but also failed to set the `next` field of the newly allocated tail node to `NULL`. There is a further problem in this function: both the `push_head()` and the `push_tail()` functions need to create and return a node pointer when called with a `NULL` `head` pointer. The original `push_head()` function does this, but the `push_tail()` function does not. If the first number entered by the user is odd, the first node is added to the list via the `push_tail()` function, leading to undefined behavior (most likely a segmentation fault).

More importantly, you should work on simplifying your code. This will make it easier to write, and easier to debug. For example, your `print()` function can be reduced to three lines:

```
void print(ll_node_ptr current)
{
    while(current) {
        printf("%d\n", current->v);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

There are several things that can be done to improve the `push_tail()` function. Here is a new version:

```
ll_node_ptr push_tail(ll_node_ptr head, int v)
{
    ll_node_ptr current = head;
    ll_node_ptr prev = NULL;
    ll_node_ptr tail = malloc(sizeof(ll_node));

    if (tail == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Tail node allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    tail->v = v;
    tail->next = NULL;

    while (current) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (head) {
        prev->next = tail;
    } else {
        head = tail;
    }

    return head;
}
```

You do not need to cast the result of `malloc()`. [Opinions differ on whether or not you should do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), but writing without the cast simplifies the code. Also, you should check to make sure that `malloc()` has successfully allocated the requested memory. This is especially important if you are instead using `realloc()`, because failing to do so can lead to memory leaks. After the new tail node is created here, the `v` and `next` fields are immediately set.

It usually seems simpler to iterate over a linked list by looking at the `current` node, rather than by looking at the `current->next` node. Use of the `prev` node pointer facilitates this. The new function iterates over the list until `current == NULL`, at which point `prev` points to the last node of the list. In the event that `head` was passed in as a `NULL` pointer (i.e., the list was empty, which can happen if the first number entered by the user is odd) the iteration loop is skipped, since `current` is initialized to `head`. The code after the loop sets the `next` field of the last node to point to the newly created tail node if a nonempty list was given to the function, otherwise `head` becomes the new tail node. Finally, `head` is returned to the calling function.

There is much simplification that could be applied to the `pop_el()` function, and a lot of superfluous code. This function should really be completely redesigned. Where you have:

```
previous->next = current ->next;
free(current);
current = current->next;
```

You have `free`d the memory referenced by `current`, then you try to dereference the pointer to this memory. After the call to `free()`, you no longer own this memory, and this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Instead you want:

```
current = previous->next;
```

But this does not really matter, because `found` is next set to `1`, the loop terminates, and the function `return`s `backup`, with no more uses of `current`. You should just remove the above assignment to `current` since it is not needed.

You should be able to use this information to improve the rest of the code in your program. There are other issues that you may want to look at. It is generally a bad practice to `typedef` pointers-- this only serves to obfuscate the code and increases the likelihood of programming errors. The specification that you provided does not make it clear what should happen if there are multiple nodes containing the same value, i.e., should one or all be removed? And, what if the first number entered by the user is `0`?

Answer (score -1):

First of all i would suggest using recursive functions when working with lists. Its much easier to debug and understand.

I think i found an issue with your push_tail function:

```
current->next = (ll_node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(ll_node));
current->v = v;
```

You allocate memory for current->next but assign the value to the current node.
This should be

```
current->next = (ll_node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(ll_node));
current->next->v = v;
current->next->next = NULL;
```

Maybe this has something to do with your problem.

Comment: "Maybe this has something to do with your problem" is a sure sign that this is not a suitable answer.  It would be better for the OP and for everyone else for him to solve the problem for himself, but if you're going to post an answer then at least explain why it solves the problem he asked about.  Otherwise, you have a comment, not an answer.

Comment: well he asked for clues ;)

Comment: that's exactly what i did, i asked for clues, not to solve my problem.
I wasn't trying to make the community do my homeworks, that's my job, i was rather asking to point me to the source of my problems, so i could solve them by myself

Comment: @Vitek-- your solution invokes undefined behavior if `head` is a `NULL` pointer, which will happen if the first number entered by the user is odd.